# What to write in an Exception detail message?

Tags: java, exception, coding-style

I can't seem to find an answer anywhere?

I'm fairly new to using exceptions in Java so I'm not exactly sure what I should be writing (if anything) in the exception detail message.  This isn't anything that will be published just as a learning programmer.

Should I write something like-

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input null or empty");
```

Or-

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input cannot be null or empty");
```

Just some sort of guidelines or overview or experience tips or anything if possible would be great!

Edit- Sorry I didn't realize the rule about not asking opinion questions.  I don't know how to rephrase this question to not be an opinion question though.

Comment: put a full stop at the end. :)

Comment: These two are equivalent. The important thing is to give enough contextual information. Maybe the parameter name instead of "input"?

Comment: The first time the exception actually happens, and you find it in your log... THEN you'll know better what it should say. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just some sort of guidelines or overview or experience tips or anything if possible would be great!

You should write a short message which explains the problem as clearly as you can.  At a minimum it can state what the value was, but it is better IMHO to explain that the value was invalid as well.

Comment: Good to know!  Thanks for the response!  So I should say something like ("X param null or empty: " + X)?

Comment: @TimmayB It can be useful to know which one it was, null or empty. IN other cases it might be out of bounds and it can be useful to include the value and what the bounds were.

Answer (score 1):

IllegalArgumentException is a subclass of RuntimeException just like what you have above is correct both messages in the code causes the program to terminate and print the specified error message. However, there is no specific "guidelines or overview" for the message but I personally like something specific to your variable or error which would make your job or other programmers job easier to investigate your code if that exception occurs.

Good question and happy that your are not just reading a book or tutorial , you are in fact questioning and understanding how things should be done. Keep up the good work :)

Comment: Thank you, I will try my best! :)
And thanks for the response!